# add class to internal links in content

Tags: filters

i want to add a class to all links inside of the_content, that point to other interal content, f.ex. other posts and pages. i want to do this automatically. dunno if the best practise would be, to look for content or try to hook into the tinymce editor.. and eather way around, i don't know how..

this is what i have:

```
<a title="title" href="url">text</a>
```

and i want it to be

```
<a title="title" href="url" class="class">text</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't want to use js, i wanted a php solution, plus i also manipulate all internal links into anchor links. in the end, you have to decide for yourself, what would be the best way for you, php or js.

this goes into functions.php inside the current theme folder.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'crawl_content');
function crawl_content( $text ) {
    $url = str_replace("/", "\/", "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
    $search = '/href="https?:\/\/' . $url . '(?:[^\/"]+\/)*([^\/"]+)+\/"/';
    preg_match_all( $search, $text, $matches);
    for ($a = 0; $a < count($matches[0]); $a++)    {
        $new = "href=\"#" . $matches[1][$a] . "\" class=\"newsLink\"";
        $text = preg_replace('%' . $matches[0][$a] . '%', $new, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

internal links without the filter look like this:

```
<a title="title" href="http://example.com/some-random-subdings-or-not/post-slug/">Link Text</a>
```

with the filter it looks like this:

```
<a title="title" href="#post-slug" class="newsLink">Link Text</a>
```

external links will be left as they are.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in jquery on document load. Using addClass

```
$("#DivName").find("a").addClass("YourClassHere");
```

Comment: hi and thanks for the help. but nope. this would catch ALL links, but i only want the internal ones. guess php is the only way..

Comment: you can use filter to check what the href value is.  [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713222/add-class-to-all-links-that-link-to-a-certain-domain-with-js-jquery) here